# Where did Socrates describe the tripartite of the soul in the Republic?

Tags: plato, souls, the-republic

Reading through the books I to V, I couldn't a real explanation about the tripartite of the soul as I could find in the Phaedo. Reading in some analysis of the books[1], and the wikipedia article about it[2] sounds like the definition of the 3 parts are described through the book IV, however reading and listening the audibook from the book IV, is hard to pin-point where exactly those points are defined.

References:

[1] https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-ethics-politics/

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato%27s_theory_of_soul#The_tripartite_soul

Answer (score 1):

You will find Plato's analysis of the tripartite soul in Book IV 436 - 439. In the *Republic*, he presents his analysis as a comparison of the soul and the city. First, he identifies the three parts in the city and then finds the same (or similar) parts in the soul. So his account here is different from his account in the *Phaedrus*. You didn't miss the charioteer in the *Republic*. He is only in the *Phaedrus*.